# How to select some of test cases to compose the BAT test(build acceptance test)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, suite

In junit test, should I create another test suite named as ExampleBAT to do this, and this test suite contains the selected test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BVT/BAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_verification_test) is a short set of tests which is done after the build and exercises the main functionality. So for (large) applications, JUnit might not be the right choice for this kind of tests. I'd design those test to be performed by hand or a different test framework which is capable to automate tests for applications or systems.

The BVT/BAT just proves, that the build was good enough to create a useable application (can be executed, user interface is accessible, can load data from database, ...).

Comment: Firstly, write test cases with Junit, then we could leverage ant to automate the test.